# Real time data from VB.net app to web server

Tags: vb.net, real-time

I'm fairly new to VB.net programming. I'd like some suggestions for methods/procedures for sending real time data from a VB.net app to a web server (asp.net) for real time display. My question relates to the best method to send the data from the desktop app and the best way to receive and handle the data on the server. I'm not asking for sample code, just some idea of what methods to research. I am currently using a text file upload method but I'm sure there is  a more efficient way of achieving this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you can research System.Net.HttpWebRequest and System.Net.WebCLient.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data to the server, you may research about webservice or WCF.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

For retrieving data from the server to your ASP.Net application, you can research about AJAX.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVC framework for ASP.NET (which I strongly recommend over WebForms), MVC4 which has recently gone into RC mode features a very nice new web API:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

"ASP.NET MVC 4 includes ASP.NET Web API, a new framework for creating HTTP services that can reach a broad range of clients including browsers and mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is also an ideal platform for building RESTful services."

It allows you to define quite simple methods on the server which work directly with your actual domain objects and it does the work of returning data in an appropriate content type (e.g. JSON, XML) based either on the incoming request or a specific configuration you may set.

Your web app could then poll the GET methods on the same API controller class via Ajax (jQuery is nice) to display the results.